# Assign a static elastic IP to an instance in Autoscaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I have one instance in ASG, I need to assign an elastic ip that instance. Now when the instance health check fails, the newly launched instance should have the same elastic IP. The IAM role and everything is in the correct order.

Comment: There are many tutorials on how to do it (e.g. [here](https://medium.com/@lakshman301195/elastic-ip-in-an-auto-scaling-group-a43c3bc9e74) or [here](https://binx.io/blog/2019/09/02/how-to-dynamically-bind-elastic-ip-addresses-to-an-auto-scaling-group/)). Thus, what exactly is the issue? Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes, I created one Cloudformation template, in that had executed some bash script as a user data. Now I'm creating an elastic ip in the template itself. Not sure how to take that IP from the resource itself and pass it as a user data in Launch configuration.

Comment: Here's a similar method, but using a domain name with Route 53: [Amazon Route 53: How to automatically update IP addresses without using Elastic IPs - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/amazon-route-53-how-to-automatically-update-ip-addresses-without-using-elastic-ips-h7o)

Comment: Thanks, John Rotenstein for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
            MAXWAIT=3
            ALLOC_ID=${IPAddresses}
            echo "Checking if EIP with ALLOC_ID[$ALLOC_ID] is free...."
            ISFREE=$(aws ec2 describe-addresses --allocation-ids $ALLOC_ID --query Addresses[].InstanceId --output text --region ${AWS::Region})
            STARTWAIT=$(date +%s)
            while [ ! -z "$ISFREE" ]; do
              if [ "$(($(date +%s) - $STARTWAIT))" -gt $MAXWAIT ]; then
                echo "WARNING: We waited 30 seconds, we're forcing it now."
                ISFREE=""
              else
                echo "Waiting for EIP with ALLOC_ID[$ALLOC_ID] to become free...."
                sleep 3
                ISFREE=$(aws ec2 describe-addresses --allocation-ids $ALLOC_ID --query Addresses[].InstanceId --output text --region ${AWS::Region})
              fi
            done
            echo Running: aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --allocation-id $ALLOC_ID --allow-reassociation --region ${AWS::Region}}
            aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --allocation-id $ALLOC_ID --allow-reassociation --region ${AWS::Region}
            yum install  jq -y
```

Answer (score 1):

> Not sure how to take that IP from the resource itself and pass it as a user data in Launch configuration.

In the CFN, it would look similar to the following:

```
Resources:

    MyEIP:
        Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
        Properties: {}

    MyLaunchTemplate:
        Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
        Properties:           
            UserData:
              Fn::Base64: !Sub |
                #!/bin/bash -xe

                EIP_IP=${MyEIP}

                echo ${!EIP_IP}

                # use aws cli to attach EIP_IP to the instance
```

**Instance role** would be required as well with permissions to attach the EIP.

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip.html#aws-properties-ec2-eip-return-values) about `!Ref` which will be used when `EIP_IP=${MyEIP}`:

> When you pass the logical ID of this resource to the intrinsic Ref function, **Ref returns the Elastic IP address**.

Comment: Role is not an issue

Comment: @GovindKumar Good to hear role is correct. But for future reference it is good idea to mention it as well if someone else reads the question.

Comment: My IP will return an allocation Id?

Comment: Have you tested this snippet? Could you please confirm?

Comment: @GovindKumar I can't test it right now. The template I provided is a `pseudo-type` example. It will not work by just copying and pasting sadly. You need to modify it to your use-case.

Comment: But, here in this case, user data will be like a simple string and I don't think that we can pass the value in user data in an straight forward order.

Comment: @GovindKumar I think it would be good to update your question with exactly what template you have, why it does not work, what errors do you get and more. Otherwise its difficult to speculate on your issue based on these comments. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

With EC2 & Auto scaling, You need using `user data` in EC2 to Auto Attach Elastic IP to EC2 Instance For Auto scaling

```
#!/bin/bash
aws configure set aws_access_key_id "XYZ..."
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "ABC..."
aws configure set region "ap-..."
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id "$(curl -X GET "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")" --public-ip your_elastic_IP
```

**Note: you should create new user & IAM have only permission associate-address to create/get aws key**

Hope it be help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for multiple elastic ip is execute this script in user_data of launch configuration associated to auto scaling group.

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG_FILE="/var/log/elasticipasociation.log"
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
ALLOC_ID=("eipalloc-XXXXX" "eipalloc-XXXXX" "eipalloc-XXXX")
exec > >(tee "$LOG_FILE") 2>&1
for id in "${ALLOC_ID[@]}"; do
        ISFREE=$(aws ec2 describe-addresses --allocation-ids $id --query Addresses[].InstanceId --output text --region $AWS_REGION )
        echo -e "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')""- Iniciando Asociacion de IP Elastica..."
        echo -e "Chequeando si la Elastic IP "$id" esta libre..."
        if [ -z "$ISFREE" ]; then
                echo -e "La IP Elastica "$id" esta libre..."
                echo -e "Realizando Asociacion de IP "$id" Elastica con Instancia "$ISFREE"..."
                aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --allocation-id $ALLOC_ID --allow-reassociation --region $AWS_REGION
                echo -e "---------------------------------------------------"
                exit
        else
                echo -e "La IP Elastica "$id" esta en uso por la instancia id "$ISFREE"..."
                echo -e "Vamos a intentar con la siguiente IP Elastica..."
                echo -e "---------------------------------------------------"
        fi
done
```